# How to Drop Table with Where clause / condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to drop tables (multiple tables) from the database (Postgres) which has suffix 'alpha'. There are almost 500 tables present in the database which has different suffixes and I am willing to drop tables only with the suffix 'alpha'.

Table Name Example: inventory_20170312_alpha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s;' ,
              (SELECT string_agg(table_name, ',') 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE table_name LIKE '%alpha'));
```

Warning! I've assumed there is no FK to other tables.

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ff286132fcb3e25dd0eb53d64f8acc64)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below. If you are working on a real product or something like that, please run it on a test environment first. Also make sure your userid has the permission of dropping a table in the database.

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(4000)
DECLARE cmds CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'drop table [' + Table_Name + ']'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE Table_Name LIKE '%alpha'

OPEN cmds
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH cmds INTO @cmd
    IF @@fetch_status != 0 BREAK
    EXEC(@cmd)
END
CLOSE cmds;
DEALLOCATE cmds
```

Comment: I'd also add, make sure you have an up to date backup.

Comment: nice point! @Andrew

Comment: That is not valid for Postgres

Comment: The above format is not working for me. It's giving me a syntax error for a declaration of '@cmd'